# 18.04 headphone jack no sound after installing remotemouse

Tags: unity, pulseaudio, indicator, mono, xdotool

So recently I was able to plug in my headphones to my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop, but now I am not getting any sound. I think it may because I did an apt install of "mono-complete", "xdotool" and "libappindicator3-0.1-cil-dev". I have purged all of these, and it still will not allow me to hear what is going on in my headphones. I am also using ubuntu-unity-desktop instead of the 18.04 default desktop as well.

Yes, I have checked if things are muted, autoremoved and cleaned apt-get, removed /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/*, did 'alsa force-reload', rebooted computer, removed ~/.conf ~/.pulse etc. that is already online.

Here is what /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf looks like (after I tried editting it and rebooting): http://paste.debian.net/1048009/

Here is also what /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones-2.conf looks like after editing and rebooting: http://paste.debian.net/1048010/

I do get a bunch of mentions in the ....paths/analog-output-headphones.conf about "mono". If "mono-complete" package is breaking pulseaudio, then I don't know how to get rid of it.
Here is the

I was trying to use [RemoteMouse](https://www.remotemouse.net/), which required those packages to be installed, if that helps anyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 3 hours of troubleshooting:
Open terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio alsa-base
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm -rf ~/.conf/pulse/
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/pavucontrol.ini
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio utils
sudo reboot
```

(wait for reboot, log back in and open terminal)

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils alsa-base ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-unity-desktop
sudo reboot
```

Not sure if all those steps were necessary, but after 3 hours, I'm fed up with trying minimalist solutions. Hope this helps!

Comment: Did not succeed in restoring a missing alsamixer when I tried in 18.04

Comment: caution! this answer is harmful. do backups. my problem was "no sound in headphones", and after following this instruction I don't have sound at all (pulse audio shows a Dummy device). Ubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Here is the way that I found which may work for your system, as I have Ubuntu 18.04 with ubuntu-unity-desktop too. 
Type in your cmd prompt:
    `alsamixer`
It will show you system sound control, where you can try to play, and adjust around. Try to turn on all the `MM` bars (which is muted) or switch to other sound cards if you have.

While you are adjusting them, go to Setting>>Sound>>Test Sound, try to test it if it works.

Good luck.